# group $G$ of order $312$. show that G is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory, normal-subgroups

I have a group G of order $312$ and I need to show $G$ is not simple.

What I tried :

I know $312 = 2^3\times39$

so, I know that I have an element of order $2$.

does that mean I have a subgroup of order $2$?

If so then I remember that any subgroup of order $2$ is normal

But, I couldn't figure out the reason for that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any subgroup of *index* two is normal, not order.

Comment: Hint: How many Sylow subgroups are there of order $13$?

Comment: ohhh no. so I only have an element and a group of order 2?

Comment: i don't know.. I guess 1 because 13 is only once there?

Comment: ok i think i got it - $n_{13} = 1 (mod 13) $ and $n_{13} devides 24$ so $n_{13} = 1$  ? then if $n_p = 1 $ then this sylow subgroup is normal? many thanks

Comment: This is a proof that every subgroup of index $2$ is normal:
Let $N$ be a subgroup of index $2$ in a finite group $G$. Then we can partition $G$ into two (disjoint) cosets $N$ and $gN$, where $g\in G \setminus N$.
Let $x \in G$. Then if $x\in N$, we have that $xN=N=Nx$, but if $x \notin N$, then $xN=G \setminus N=Nx$; again the left coset is always equal to the right coset, and we're done!

Comment: thanks. how did you get from xN = G\N  to  = Nx ?

Comment: That $xN=G/N=Nx$ follows from the fact that cosets partition the group, and since there are only two right cosets and two left cosets, the left coset that is not the identity equals the right coset that is not the identity.

Comment: You might want to post a brief answer that the Sylow $13$-group is normal, so this question moves off the unanswered list.

Comment: @BenWest: I already did it. Try giving it an upvote so we can remove it from the queue (it's community wiki anyway)

Comment: @Prism Done! ${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to remove this post from unanswered queue.

Let $n_{13}$ be the number of Sylow $13$-subgroup of $G$. Then by Sylow's Theorem, $n_{13}\equiv 1 \text{(mod }13)$ and $n_{13}$ divides $2^3\cdot 3 = 24$. This implies $n_{13}=1$, so that there is only one Sylow $13$-subgroup, which is consequently normal. The last assertion follows from the fact conjugation preserves the order of a subgroup. So if there is only one subgroup $H$ of order $13$, then for any $g\in G$, we have $|g H g^{-1}| = |H| = 13$, so $g H g^{-1} = H$, i.e. $H$ is normal.